# multi player games using WCF

Tags: wcf

I want to program a game using WCF.I am using a single object of game that is used by all consumers. How can I notify all of the other players when one of the players have made a move?

Answer (score 2):

May I suggest you take a look at XNA instead. It is a managed framework for writing games for Windows, Xbox 360 and Zune, and it has support for multiple players, handling graphics and so forth. More information at http://creators.xna.com/en-US/